How to collect your own massive data for big AI projects
How are some companies collecting data for AI projects, for instance openAI (chatGPT), Midjourney, or even those text to video models that will be available soon ?
What kind of approaches are they using ? And in general how to collect big amounts of data relatively quick ?

Here is a blog post about common approaches and problems (webz.io)
One common "web-scale datasource" is called "Common Crawl", When downloading it, you might trigger rate limit errors with their IP provider,   See status page for past incidents.
A cleaner version of the common crawl is the Collossal Clean Crawled Corpus (C4) dataset, 804 GB on  Tensorflow Hub.
